# Load-Balancing with ARR + IIS on ports other than 80

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, arr

Is there any way to use ARR to re-route requests to ports other than 80/443 (the default http/https ports, respectively)? We have several web applications that listen on ports other than 80 and would like to load-balance them using ARR. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this - when adding a server to the farm, click the "Advanced settings..." link, in there both the HTTP and HTTPS ports are configurable to whatever you want.

In the `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config` file, the server entry would look something like this:

```
<server address="192.168.1.1" enabled="true">
    <applicationRequestRouting httpPort="8080" />
</server>
```

Depending on how your web application works, you may also need to turn on the "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" setting in the Proxy configuration for your farm.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot of how to do it ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/09/01/configuring-application-request-routing-arr-to-use-a-port-other-than-port-80/)):

[image: using other ports]