# IIS Cluster with ARR+NLB - Multiple Ports

Tags: iis, cluster, arr, nlb, farm

I have two servers with NLB and ARR. And I have two IIS servers behind ARR.

For now, as I tested, it only routes 80 and 443 ports. Can I route all ports (or may be defined ones) from ARR to IIS servers?

Tried some URL rewrite rules but without success

Found answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/132081/load-balancing-with-arr-iis-on-ports-other-than-80) - explained how to change http port, but as I have different services on different ports, I need to route all of them (or specified ones)

[Cluster Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvmV.png)

Please check the Cluster Diagram. As shown on diagram, I Installed NLB on ARR01 and ARR02, configured virtual IP for HA and installed ARR on both (ARR01 and ARR02) servers for routing web requests on IIS01 and IIS02 servers.

The routing of 80 and 443 port is working well. But as I mentioned, I need to route also different ports (ex. 8080, 8081, etc) from ARR to IIS servers.

Comment: I haven't used NLB in a long time, but IIRC you can create port rules to route whatever TCP ports you need from NLB to IIS.

Comment: NLB is already configured to accept all ports.